# File returned by flask's send_file is slightly larger than original

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-services, flask

I've written a POST method in Flask that simply returns a static file loaded from disk:

```
from PIL import Image
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/score', methods=['POST'])
def score():
    return send_file('/data/temp.tif')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I call the web service as follows:

```
curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:5000/score -i --output /data/temp2.tif
```

I am surprised to find that the file returned to me is not the same size as the original file:

```
# ls -al /data/*.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 331030 Oct  8 21:23 /data/temp.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 331338 Oct  8 21:33 /data/temp2.tif
```

Moreover the file size difference has important consequences, because while the original is a valid TIFF file, the "copy" returned by the web service is not a valid TIFF file:

```
>>> import tifffile
>>> tifffile.imread('/data/temp.tif').shape
(158, 238, 2)
>>> tifffile.imread('/data/temp2.tif')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 444, in imread
    with TiffFile(files, **kwargs_file) as tif:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 1754, in __init__
    raise ValueError('not a TIFF file')
ValueError: not a TIFF file
```

I'm using Python 2.7.12 and Flask version 1.0.2. Any help identifying the cause of the problem is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem: I should not have used the `-i` option for curl, which was causing the headers to be saved along with the response body. All's well now that I've switched to

```
curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:5000/score --output /data/temp2.tif
```